# Global Position of a model OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to get the global position of a model throughout an entire game?

[image]

I'm trying to figure out where those values come from.. Depending on how I rotate the camera, those values change.

Different positions:

[image]
[image]

[image]

From gDebugger, I got these values:

```
LOWEST ANGLE:


GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99975264, 0.0091297952, -0.020280767, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{0.022241013, -0.41039214, 0.9116379, 0}
{1819.2891, -308.66016, 5129.084, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99975264, 0.0091297952, -0.020280767, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{0.022241013, -0.41039214, 0.9116379, 0}
{1819.2891, -308.66016, 5129.084, 1}


GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99990994, 0.0055096098, -0.01223895, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{0.013421912, -0.41045669, 0.91178131, 0}
{255.48047, -56.457031, 4179.0703, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99990994, 0.0055096098, -0.01223895, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{0.013421912, -0.41045669, 0.91178131, 0}
{255.48047, -56.457031, 4179.0703, 1}



GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99977756, 0.0086575896, -0.019231817, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{0.021090677, -0.41040236, 0.91166061, 0}
{248.38477, -85.074219, 4242.6367, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99977756, 0.0086575896, -0.019231817, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{0.021090677, -0.41040236, 0.91166061, 0}
{248.38477, -85.074219, 4242.6367, 1}



GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99966991, -0.010546137, 0.023427004, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{-0.025691351, -0.41035816, 0.91156244, 0}
{223.3418, -60.19043, 4187.3594, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99966991, -0.010546137, 0.023427004, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{-0.025691351, -0.41035816, 0.91156244, 0}
{223.3418, -60.19043, 4187.3594, 1}


HIGHEST:

GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99966991, -0.010546137, 0.023427004, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{-0.025691351, -0.41035816, 0.91156244, 0}
{223.3418, -60.19043, 4187.3594, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99966991, -0.010546137, 0.023427004, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{-0.025691351, -0.41035816, 0.91156244, 0}
{223.3418, -60.19043, 4187.3594, 1}





GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99997616, 0.0060372208, -0.0033470246, 0}
{0, 0.48486927, 0.87458664, 0}
{0.006902942, -0.87456578, 0.48485771, 0}
{3551.2305, 297.58008, 5957.9141, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99997616, 0.0060372208, -0.0033470246, 0}
{0, 0.48486927, 0.87458664, 0}
{0.006902942, -0.87456578, 0.48485771, 0}
{3551.2305, 297.58008, 5957.9141, 1}


GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99997616, 0.0027075345, -0.0063497927, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{0.006902942, -0.39221969, 0.91984564, 0}
{-281.65234, -45.993164, 4131.0254, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99997616, 0.0027075345, -0.0063497927, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{0.006902942, -0.39221969, 0.91984564, 0}
{-281.65234, -45.993164, 4131.0254, 1}


GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99960816, 0.010978992, -0.02574827, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{0.027991278, -0.39207536, 0.91950715, 0}
{249.30078, -64.625977, 4174.7188, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99960816, 0.010978992, -0.02574827, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{0.027991278, -0.39207536, 0.91950715, 0}
{249.30078, -64.625977, 4174.7188, 1}





GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99992931, -0.004879978, 0.010840298, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{-0.011888071, -0.41046464, 0.91179901, 0}
{-287.10938, -74.085938, 4218.2285, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99992931, -0.004879978, 0.010840298, 0}
{0, 0.91186345, 0.41049367, 0}
{-0.011888071, -0.41046464, 0.91179901, 0}
{-287.10938, -74.085938, 4218.2285, 1}
GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}




GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99963969, 0.023475286, -0.013014656, 0}
{0, 0.48486927, 0.87458664, 0}
{0.026841579, -0.87427151, 0.48469457, 0}
{-215.40039, -576.11523, 6158.7266, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99963969, 0.023475286, -0.013014656, 0}
{0, 0.48486927, 0.87458664, 0}
{0.026841579, -0.87427151, 0.48469457, 0}
{-215.40039, -576.11523, 6158.7266, 1}
GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}



GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99963969, 0.023475286, -0.013014656, 0}
{0, 0.48486927, 0.87458664, 0}
{0.026841579, -0.87427151, 0.48469457, 0}
{-215.40039, -576.11523, 6158.7266, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99963969, 0.023475286, -0.013014656, 0}
{0, 0.48486927, 0.87458664, 0}
{0.026841579, -0.87427151, 0.48469457, 0}
{-215.40039, -576.11523, 6158.7266, 1}
GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}



GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.99959737, -0.011129435, 0.026101092, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{-0.028374836, -0.39207113, 0.91949719, 0}
{-250.26758, -71.263672, 4190.2871, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.99959737, -0.011129435, 0.026101092, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{-0.028374836, -0.39207113, 0.91949719, 0}
{-250.26758, -71.263672, 4190.2871, 1}
GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}


GL_CURRENT_MATRIX_ARB: 
{0.23925836, 0.38083714, -0.89315093, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{0.97095597, -0.093844078, 0.22008601, 0}
{2911.0664, 370.13428, 3481.4473, 1}
GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX: 
{1.40625, -0, 0, 0}
{0, -2.1556885, 0, 0}
{0, -0, 1.0273149, 1}
{0, -0, -405.46298, 0}
GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX: 
{0.23925836, 0.38083714, -0.89315093, 0}
{0, 0.91986758, 0.39222905, 0}
{0.97095597, -0.093844078, 0.22008601, 0}
{2911.0664, 370.13428, 3481.4473, 1}
GL_VIEWPORT: {4, 165, 512, 334}
```

What can  do with them? Is there a way I can get the camera location with it? Or the character's global position?

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL's matrices exist for one purpose: rendering. That's why they include the camera matrix. The onus is on *your code* to know where objects are. You tell OpenGL where things are, and OpenGL renders them; that's how it's supposed to work.

To put it another way, if you don't know where an object is in the world, how can you expect OpenGL to, since you told it where to put it?

Comment: I was thinking that there would be a way to use these matrices to get the camera matrix.

I was reading: http://3dengine.org/Modelview_matrix

And it said the the camera center is at the middle of the viewport. It's always like that for this game.

What do the last 4 rows do? Mine seems to change whenever I change the camera location.

There is no way to get the camera position and look from the info I provided right?

Comment: Hey can you tell me how GLIntercept's FreeCam works? How does it get camera position and how is it able to move it :S I'm trying to do the same thing as GLintercept's Freecam.